# Unable to build Apache Cordova using Visual Studio 2015 RC on Windows 7

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am unable to build an Apache Cordova app using VS 2015RC on Windows 7. It throws these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'angular'. App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 9
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'angular'. App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 19
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'ng'.  App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 24
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'ng'.  App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 25
Error   TS2305  Module 'Ionic' has no exported member 'IConfigProvider'.    App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 26
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'ng'.  App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 94
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'ng'.  App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 110
Error   TS2305  Module 'Ionic' has no exported member 'ILoading'.   App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\App.ts 110
Error   TS2305  Module 'Ionic' has no exported member 'IHistory'.   App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\controllers\navigationController.ts    17
Error   TS2305  Module 'Ionic' has no exported member 'ITabsDelegate'.  App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\controllers\navigationController.ts    18
Error   TS6053  File 'C:/Users/Justas/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/cordovatest/cordovatest/App/ts/lib/typings/definitelytyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts' not found.   App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\imports.ts 1
Error   TS6053  File 'C:/Users/Justas/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/cordovatest/cordovatest/App/ts/lib/typings/definitelytyped/cordova/cordova.d.ts' not found. App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\imports.ts 2
Error   TS6053  File 'C:/Users/Justas/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/cordovatest/cordovatest/App/ts/lib/typings/definitelytyped/cordova-ionic/cordova-ionic.d.ts' not found. App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\imports.ts 3
Error   TS6053  File 'C:/Users/Justas/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/cordovatest/cordovatest/App/ts/lib/typings/definitelytyped/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts' not found. App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\imports.ts 4
Error   TS6053  File 'C:/Users/Justas/documents/visual studio 2015/Projects/cordovatest/cordovatest/App/ts/lib/typings/ionic-typescript-definitions/beta14/ionic.d.ts' not found.   App C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\imports.ts 5
```

I've tried reinstalling vs-tac, installing all the related libraries via NuGet packet manager but that did not resolve the problem. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I'm using this guide - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn771551.aspx

Update: My imports.ts file has these lines:

```
/// <reference path="lib/typings/definitelytyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="lib/typings/definitelytyped/cordova/cordova.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="lib/typings/definitelytyped/cordova-ionic/cordova-ionic.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="lib/typings/definitelytyped/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="lib/typings/ionic-typescript-definitions/beta14/ionic.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Hi, @Eustace - can you please share the contents of your imports.ts file, I think the issue has to do with the File ... not found error messages.

Comment: Hello @JordanMatthiesen, I've added the imports.ts contents. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that - also, just making sure, if you navigate in Windows Explorer to 'C:\Users\Justas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\cordovatest\cordovatest\App\ts\lib\typings\definitelytyped\angularjs\angular.d.ts'  does the file exist?

Comment: Those files do not exist. I've tried adding them manually / installing TypeScript (since it was not present) but that did not solve the problem. However, I've switched to CLI and it seems to work fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the update - can you clarify what CLI you switched to? Also, where did you get the .d.ts files you're trying to reference (I assume DefinitelyTyped).

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer re: setting up the files, for the benefit of others reading this post.

Comment: I just removed VS and went through this guide - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface. Had to manually set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_PATH but everything runs fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the files you reference in your imports.ts file, make sure they're all present at those file paths on disk. You should be able to download all the definitions from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped. As for the Ionic definitions, it looks like you're trying to use https://github.com/danibo86/ionic-typescript-definitions, which should work. With these at the correct file path, your project should build.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable external modules for the TypeScript compiler.
If you are using gulp-typescript, set it in the ts project def:

```
noExternalResolve: false
```

Comment: I think I'm using just regular typescript. I've tried adding noExternalResolve: false to taco.json and tried creating a tsconfig.json in the project directory with this line but that did not resolve my issue. Tried renaming some files in the TypeScript dir (Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript) and it ended up breaking the project so I assume it's being loaded.  Could you please provide more details on where to insert your suggested line?